# Most efficient way to call a restfulAPI in firefox?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, firefox-os

We have the endpoint, for example

http://someurl.com/some_random_crap/parameter_a/some_other_randome_crap/parameter_b

I want to call the this with as few key strokes as possible in a firefox/chrome tab with parameter_a, parameter_b changed.

Is there a plugin that does this?

Comment: Did you intend to add the tag for Firefox OS?

Comment: firefox-addon is not compatible with WebExtensions. You probably meant `firefox-webextensions`